# Как правиьно подключить скрипты в виде?

Tags: yii2

Каким образом можно подключить скрипт после подключения всех скриптов (интересует конкретно jQuery)
попытался таким образом.

```
$this->registerJsFile(Yii::getAlias('@backendWebroot').'/js/morris.min.js',['position' => yii\web\View::POS_READY]);
```

не выводится вообще, через  POS_LOAD таже ситуация.
если таким как понимаете сразу после тега

```
$this->registerJsFile(Yii::getAlias('@backendWebroot').'/js/morris.min.js',['position' => yii\web\View::POS_END]);
```

Comment: Как я понял Вам нужно подключить morris.min.js в самом конце? После всех скриптов?

Comment: да вы правильно поняли

Comment: сорри, что поздно :) Вылетело из головы тогда и забыл вернутся к вопросу :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если хотите подключить выше указанный скрипт после **Jquery**, то вот так:

```
$this->registerJsFile(Yii::getAlias('@backendWebroot').'/js/morris.min.js', ['yii\web\JqueryAsset']);
```

---

Если будете подключать скрипты через **AssetBundle**, то нужно будет указать массив зависимостей.

Например:

```
<?

namespace app\assets;

use yii\web\AssetBundle;

class TestAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $baseUrl = '@web';

    public $js = [
        'js/morris.min.js'
    ];

    public $depends = [
        'yii\web\JqueryAsset',
    ];
}
```